# Using symbols to index other symbols in an expression which is summed and integrated over in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I'm a beginner in SymPy. I having trouble writing the following expression:

[image]

where `f` and `g` are actual functions, say squaring and cubing respectively.

For my `x` and `a` variables (imagine I have more than two of those), I tried using

- `MatrixSymbol`
- `MutableDenseNDimArray`
- `IndexedBase` / `Idx`
- Python sequences of `Symbol`s

but things don't seem to work because I'm using a `Symbol` to index `x` which doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this where explicit integers are used as the expression is built within a loop:

```
>>> x=var('x:2')
>>> var('a:3')
(a0, a1, a2)
>>> expr = S(0)
>>> for a2 in range(2):
...  for a1 in range(2):
...   expr += Integral(f(x[a1])*g(x[a2]),(x[a1],-oo,oo),(x[a2],-oo,oo))
...
>>> print (filldedent(expr))

Integral(f(x0)*g(x0), (x0, -oo, oo), (x0, -oo, oo)) +
Integral(f(x0)*g(x1), (x0, -oo, oo), (x1, -oo, oo)) +
Integral(f(x1)*g(x0), (x1, -oo, oo), (x0, -oo, oo)) +
Integral(f(x1)*g(x1), (x1, -oo, oo), (x1, -oo, oo))
```